# Binding Panorama.SelectedIndexProperty in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

First, SelectedIndex is not exposed in markup, so you have to do it in code behind, right?

Second, I have set the binding in code behind:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("Main.PanoSelectedIndex.ObservedObject");
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
rootPano.SetBinding(Panorama.SelectedIndexProperty, binding);`
```

(ObservedObject implements iNotifyChanged)

The binding path points to my Main view model, and I can see that the PanoramaItem is updating the binding. However,the panorama does not respond when something else (a MVVM Light command) changes the binding. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Roger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from the [Windows Phone Developer FAQ](http://www.learningwindowsphone.com/blog/?p=64)

> Panorama is designed so the user is in control, there fore you cannot set SelectedIndex programmatically, or force a navigation to a panorama item.
>
> You can set the DefaultItem so that when your panorama is first launched, the panorama navigates to that item, but you can’t navigate programmatically beyond that. DefaultItem can also be used so that a back navigation feels like the item where the user was at did not change.

UPDATE: You can use the `DefaultItem` to save/restore the selection for a `Panorama` as shown below (code from Jeff Prosise's [recent blog post](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/02/02/tombstoning-panorama-controls-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone.aspx)):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
 // Save the Panorama control's SelectedIndex in page state
 State["Index"] = PanoramaControl.SelectedIndex;
}
 
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
 // Restore the Panorama control's SelectedIndex
 if (State.ContainsKey("Index"))
 PanoramaControl.DefaultItem = PanoramaControl.Items[(int)State["Index"]];
}
```

Comment: Yikes! The designer of the app I am doing is not going to be happy to hear that. - Thanks

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how they are preserving it on navigate.goback. Wondering if I can manipulate it that way with teh default item. And do a navigateto instad of go back.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So to achieve it, i'd basically navigate to my page again. Wonder if there is a way to re init, etc the pano, so it looks at the default without reloading/navigating.

Comment: Not quite, you don't need to re-navigate to your page, just use the naviation events to store/restore state. When the application is tombstoned or the user navigates forwards to another page, then the `OnNavigatedFrom` method is called and you can save the `SelectedIndex`. When the application is restored from tombstoning, or the user navigates back to your page, then the `OnNavigatedTo` method is called and you can set the 'DefaultItem' property based on the index that you saved.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know SelectedIndex is a readonly property in Panorama ( Weired why WP7 SDK made it readonly). So you will get only UI change back to your VM, and you cant update UI through the VM propertychange.

And DefaultItem is the property which used to set the index programatically.

Again the issue of programatically setting an already instantiated Panorama is that, the alignment of the Title and Panoramaitem wont be in sync. Anyway I am not discouraging but there is still some chance of hack there.